# Snippet not working correctly

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

i am quite new to ST.
I created this css snippet now i want it to be universal, i mean to work just about anywhere and not just css file.
and now it works fine on html but on css the when i type  and press tab it sows this border-left property. i have emmet installed but it shoudnt conflict because b prefix is added. 
have a look at the snippet

```
    <snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[

        #${1:this}{
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>bcen</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Comment: hi @MarcAndre! what do you mean you want it to work just about anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

When I open a fresh CSS document and type `bcen` I get

```
border-length: ;
```

so it must already be an Emmet shortcut. The easiest option would be for you to change the `<tabTrigger>` of your shortcut to something that Emmet doesn't use. There are other options, like setting `"disable_tab_abbreviations": true` in your Emmet settings, but that would disable everything, which I don't think you want to do.

Since you don't have a `<scope>` set for your snippet, it should work everywhere, for every language.

Comment: Yeah but as far as i know, there is no BCEN for emmet. so why it's clashing?

Comment: @MarcAndre Based on MattDMo answer, it does expand in Emmet, so some entry does exist for it. It's also possible that it's a bug in Emmet. Perhaps file a bug on the project. It could also just have to do with how Emmet is implemented. If it simply runs a command based on tab, even if nothing "existed" for the expansion, it still wouldn't fall back to the snippet as the Emmet command was already run.